# How does the Bridge server get notified by Horizon after submitting a transaction and Compliance Server is also present?

Tags: horizon, compliance, anchor

I am trying to understand how the Bridge server gets notified by Horizon after a payment has been completed. Assuming an Anchor set up with Bridge, Compliance and Federation servers, my understanding is the following:

1. Client makes a GET request to a certain application endpoint for a payment
2. Application endpoint calls the Bridge server by making a POST:/payment request
3. Bridge server will then pass the information by making a POST:/send request to Compliance server endpoint
4. Compliance server gets the Auth endpoint from the Federation server of
   the receiving institution
5. Compliance server will then make a POST:/ (Auth endpoint of the receiving institution) to clear the transaction
6. Receiving institution replies
7. Compliance server replies back to Bridge Server with the transaction
8. Bridge server receives the transaction and submits it to Horizon
9. Horizon replies

So, which endpoint is used by Horizon to notify the Bridge server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bridge server is streaming `/accounts/{receiving-account-id}/payments` endpoint of Horizon server. When there is a new payment with a valid params (asset code) Bridge will call the [`/receive`](https://github.com/stellar/bridge-server/blob/master/readme_compliance.md#post-internal_portreceive) callback  in Compliance server (if Compliance server is connected) and then will call [receive callback](https://github.com/stellar/bridge-server/blob/master/readme_bridge.md#callbacksreceive) defined in Bridge config file.